Can I use the mains itself as a ground?
Basically, an ideal EMC/EMI filter looks like the below circuit diagram.
Ideal EMI filter circuit:

Can I use the mains itself as a ground instead of using a physical ground?
My take on EMI filter circuit:

The main goal is to use this filter circuit to make an SMPS.

Consider what this does to your common mode choke. If there is no common-mode-neutral potential, such as PE available, then you cannot shunt common mode noise away using capacitors. You can check mains filters of two-prong Class II AC/DC adapters for reference.

The first image is for 2-prong plug with no PE, the second image is for 3-prong plug with PE. What are you designing, a device with 2 or 3 prong mains plug?

Precisely what are you trying to filter and what are you trying to remove/reduce. In other words, where is the aggressor noise coming from and, where is the potential victim of the noise?

@Justme 2 prong-plug and connect the PE with Neutral.

@Andyaka Both Differential mode and common mode noise to be filtered by this circuit and the filtered Voltage has to given for High Frequency Switched Mode Power Supply.

@MrinmoySarkar the circuit you have shown is used quite often to prevent switching noise getting back onto the power-line and, you appear to be thinking it's for the other way. Depending on the choke, it may be a differential filter or, it may be a common-mode filter but, it cannot be successful in both scenarios so, I ask you to consider what are you trying to achieve with the filter you have shown.

@MrinmoySarkar Your description does not make sense. If you have a 2-prong plug, you have only Live and Neutral, no PE. So you cannot connect PE to anywhere because you don't have one and cannot make a PE from Neutral. If you have a 2-prong plug, depending on the plug being polarized or not, and how the receptacle is wired, you may expect either one of the wires to be Live and Neutral.


Can I use the mains itself as a ground instead of using a physical ground?

No. Full stop.

You don't have a ground (PE: protective earth) yet you use a common-mode choke to remove common-mode noise. This doesn't make sense because the common-mode noise is a noise that is "common" to both lines (live and neutral) i.e. the noise appears on both live and neutral and referenced to a "common" node which is PE (for mains) which is not available in your system.
The leakages of the CM choke, along with the external caps, may work as a differential mode filter but this normally doesn't require any PE connection.
So, if you don't have a PE connection you normally don't worry about the common-mode nose. If you leave the mid-junction of the 2n2 Y-caps unconnected then the leakages of the CM choke will form a differential filter with those 2n2 caps (1n1 effectively).
